# Using Tags in an Extension

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, tags

So far I made the follow changes looking for add tags functionality to my extension:

**Register a Content type**
[image]

**Add Observer methods to the extension table class**

```
class TagimagesTableTagimages extends JTable
{
    public function __construct(&$db)
    {
        parent::__construct('#__tagimages', 'cartId', $db);
        JTableObserverTags::createObserver($this, array('typeAlias' => 'com_tagimages.tagimageform'));
    }
}
```

**Add Tag fields to the form**

```
<field 
      name="tags" 
      type="tag" 
      label="Tag the image" 
      mode="ajax" 
      class="inputbox span12 small" 
      multiple="true" 
/>
```

With all this done, when I trigger the function **Save** of my Model class who extends of `JModelAdmin` class, all run okay, the values of the form I saving, they are saved in the data base table, but there is not a new record in the `#__contentitem_tag_map` and `#__ucm_content` mapping the tag with the content I saved. Not error is trigged.

Anyone know what I miss?

I already check a bit of docs like https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension but do not tell me nothing about what I doing wrong.

Comment: Please never present textual details as graphics when posting.  Please read [ask].  ...even better read Stack Overflow's How To Ask-- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  ...I should update our How To Ask.

Comment: I made it that way in that moment, since not sure why the code do not outcome preformatted in the review view. Will change as soon as possible

Comment: Have you also gone through the Adding Tags step in the Joomla MVC tutorial at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_Tags?

Comment: Yes, I did, and show the same steps I did and added here in the post. I still do not know, what I miss here, why is not working.